# How do I get 4 wolves for a Demon Hunter?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-demon-hunter

I'm very new to Diablo III, I've just played for around 2 weeks.

Today I had a **Demon Hunter** in **Torment VI** (with max bonus/sub dificulty) with **4 wolves** join our group, so I've investigated in Google and I've found the [Cloak of the Garwulf](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/the-cloak-of-the-garwulf) gear that gives you 2 more wolves (so a total of 3), but the gear is for level 50 and the bonus does not give you the other wolf so I suppose that exists a very rare Gear for level 70 that gives you 1 more wolf because I don't think that the guy that I've seen playing **Torment VI** has a 50 level gear set... really not, he got 4 wolves in total, and has 450 paragon levels (I mean legendary level) so it's really an expert.

Then what gear or which other way can give 4 wolves in total to a **Demon Hunter**?

Comment: You can *inspect* any player in the game, looking at their equipment. Find that person in your Recent Players contact group, right click -> View Profile -> Heroes -> that demon hunter -> Inspect.

Comment: OMG that will be a hard work 'cause I've played with thousands of others players with high paragon levels and I don't remember the name, but thankyou for the info, pelase could you say me how to find/acces to the 'Recent Players contact group'? If i find it I will comment the (suppossed) gear in an answer 'cause I've seen any info in Google, I think the item is very unknown for others.

Comment: Recent players is a group in your Frinds list in game, it shows last 20 people you have played with. There is no way to have 4 wolves, believe me :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have probably confused the Boar to be the fourth Wolf. There's no way to have 4 wolves, but you can have 3 Wolves, a Ferret, a Boar, a Raven and whatever's the last type is.

[Embodiment of the Marauder](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/marauders-treads) set gives you the ability to call all types of companions to your side at once.

Also, legendary levels listed on the site are **minimum** levels for that legendary to spawn, so that person was just wearing a level 70 [Cloak of the Garwulf](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/the-cloak-of-the-garwulf).

Comment: And is normal that the wolf icon next to the DemonHunter icon appeared with a number "4"? don't should be a boar icon with number "1" and a wolf icon with number "3"?. then the icon of the wolf companion with a number "4" confused me more.

Comment: Hm, maybe if you equip both of those and also choose Wolf rune, it somehow bugs out to give you four :-/ I've looked through all the Legendaries, and have not found any other items affecting Companion.

Comment: @ElektroStudios By the way, how did you see other player's pet count? The game only shows quest characters for other players, not their pets.

Comment: I'm not an expert playing in Diablo III but I've seen it in Adventure Mode, near to the player picture was shown the pets (only a wolf icon) and the pet count (4), and I've seen that the player has 4 wolves not only for the image and the count, we were in the same group killing mobs.